# MVC3 where to pu the logout display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i'm creating an MVC3 C# application. i createtd a login attribute which only appears when  a user chooses to either create,delete,or edit data stored. To logout, i put the HTML code in th layout view, but its displaying on th homepage even if the user did not log in. how do i make it display on all pages after user has logged in, and when user logs out, it is no mor displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the user is authenticated

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
   <div>control to logout</div>
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question mark as answered so the topic is closed